# How to add download .app file from html button

Tags: html

I cannot figure this one out.

Here's my code.

```html
<a class="button button-primary" href="NewApp.app" download="NewApp"><i class="fa fa-download" style="margin-top: 2px;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Download</a>
```

The app is called `NewApp`.

The `NewApp.app` file is in the same as `index.html`.

This button just downloads a random file 'NewApp.html' which doesn't exist.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, instead of `download="NewApp"`, just `download`. In HTML, I believe, to download a file, you must do the following:

```
<a href="foo.app" class="button button-primary" download>Download the app!</a>
```

It will automatically download the file that the `href` attribute is pointing towards. I hope this helps.

Comment: hi, unfortunately this downloads `download.html`.